# Data type mismatch when inserting record

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, parameters, insert

I've this piece of code for inserting records into an Access table.

`LastUpdated` field is defined as `Date/Time` at database level. It fails when inserting giving the error

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

I'm using parameterized query which avoid problems with formatting values and it's very weird because I've the same code (with more parameters) to insert records on another table on which `LastUpdated` is defined in the same way and it's working fine.

Any idea?

```
           SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO History (ActivityID, LastUpdated) VALUES (@p1,@p2)"

            With sqlcommand
                .CommandText = SqlQuery
                .Connection = SQLConnection
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", IDAct)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", DateTime.Today)
            End With
            result = sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If (result = 1) Then

                LabelWarning.Text = "Activity filled"
                LabelWarning.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen
                LabelWarning.Visible = True
                ButtonSave.Visible = False
                ButtonBack.Visible = False
                ButtonOK.Visible = True
                BlockControls()
            End If
```

Comment: which type is sqlcommand? OdbcCommand?

Comment: Are you sure that is the way you are setting the date value?

Comment: I'm completely sure @Plutonix. In fact, I have the same code for an UPDATE statemente and it's working fine. I've checked again the data type into the DB. It's defined as Date/Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is linked to parameter placeholder.

This MSDN doc states that OleDbCommand does not support named parameter (only positional) and the correct placeholder should be "?" and not "@p1".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Edit**

It turned out in comments that the placeholder have not to be so strictly adherent to the doc syntax. Only the order has to be absolutely preserved.

Explicitly declaring the parameter type however seemed to do the trick:

```
.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp)
.Parameters("@p2").Value = DateTime.Today
```

Comment: DateTime.Today is obviously a DateTime value, which type is IDAct?

Comment: `IDAct` is `Integer` but that value is not the guilty. Commenting out the `DateTime.Today` parameter line is working fine.

Comment: OleDB doesnt use named parameters *as*named params - you have to add them in the order they appear in the SQL - but it wont fail because you use "@pN" or "@firstname" if you like

Comment: have you tried something like .Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp) then .Parameters("p2").Value = DateTime.Today

Comment: @sblandin That worked like a charm! Thanks! Please post it as answer and i'll accept it